# yii2:upload is faild for file larger than 2 mb

Tags: php, file-upload, yii, yii2, yii2-extension

i used `kartik\file\FileInput`  for upload my file

my file is correct uploaded for file  smaller than 2 mb !

what is my problem ????

```
echo '<label class="control-label">اضافه کردن فایل</label>';
    echo FileInput::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'initialPreview' => [
                "../../$url",
            ],
            'initialPreviewAsData' => true,
            'initialCaption' => "",
            'initialPreviewConfig' => [
            ],
        ],
        'attribute' => 'file',
        'options' => ['multiple' => false,
            'accept' => "$acc/*",

        ]
    ]);
    }
```

this is my model :

```
class PostContent extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
    {

    public $file;
```

Comment: Have you checked file size limit ?
[Upload file size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2184541/2803788)

Comment: my problem is solved ! thanks

Comment: in .htaccess :

php_value upload_max_filesize 40M
php_value post_max_size 40M